# RabbitMQ Windows - Start Server automatically

Tags: windows-services, rabbitmq

We are working with RabbitMQ on a Windows Environment.
At the moment I have installed RabbitMQ and it runs as a Service. It starts automatically as shown here:

[image]

But if I send a Message or if I query the server here: http://localhost:15672/#/queues the server returns **404**

Now, if I open the Shell and hit this command:

```
rabbitmq-server
```

The server startup and I can send and receive messages and browse the administration page.

Questions:

- What is the difference then between RabbitMQ Windows Service and RabbitMQ Server?
- How can I have the RabbitMQ Server run as a daemon when the PC boot? Is there a command or configuration for that?

Comment: They both run the server actually. rabbitmq-server runs it as an application and the other as a service: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html .Have you tried restarting the service? Also the documentation says "The server should not be run as a service and application simultaneously." so make sure to shut down one option while trying the other one

Comment: I post an answer of what was affecting my machines

Answer (score 7):

After further investigations I found out that all RabbitMQ have been installed before configuring the plugin rabbitmq_management and amqp_client so actually the Windows Service was running without doing anything.

1. I fixed the problem on all my server by doing these steps:
2. Remove RabbitMQ using `rabbitmq-service stop`, `rabbitmq-service remove`
   Remember that the CMD must run under Administrator credentials on
   Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012
3. Install the plugin using
   `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`
4. Re-install and start the serice `rabbitmq-service install`, `rabbitmq-service start`
5. Also, I restarted Windows and verified that after the reboot the RabbitMQ was up and running.